# launch newstand when my application is tapped

Tags: ios, ios5, newsstand-kit

Is there a way where in, we can have an application icon on the home screen of the iPhone and on tapping the same the Newsstand app opens up with the magazine as the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom URLs in ios. Check out Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

To give you some brief: You app can register for custom url schema (e.g. yourapp://whatever_you_want.com?param1=value@param2=value

> To communicate with an app using a custom URL, create an NSURL object
>   with some properly formatted content and pass that object to the
>   openURL: method of the shared UIApplication object. The openURL:
>   method launches the app that registered to receive URLs of that type
>   and passes it the URL. At that point, control passes to the new app.